# When to use rel="tag"?

Tags: tags, rel, microformats

I’ve been looking at the Microformat [`rel="tag"`](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-tag), but am a little confused as to its propper use.

From the spec:

> By adding rel="tag" to a hyperlink, a page indicates that the destination of that hyperlink is an author-designated "tag" (or keyword/subject) for the current page.

What do they mean by the "destination of the hyperlink" is a "tag"?

In what situations might it be used?

Answer (score 3):

It means the page that link points to will contain a list of links to other pages that are tagged by the anchor text of that link. For example, if a link looked like this:

```
<a href="/tags/seo" rel="tag">SEO</a>
```

The microformat tells the search engine, and any other user-agent, that the URL `/tags/seo` contains links to documents (i.e. pages, etc) that are also tagged `seo`, and thus related to SEO.

If you have a tag cloud, or put tags on your content pages, you would use this microformat.